# how do I build a universal binary with xcode 3.2.6?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, powerpc

I am using XCode 3.2.6 on an Intel Mac running OS X 10.6, to build a fairly simple app that needs to be able to run under OS 10.4 on a PPC-based Mac, in addition to modern Intel-based Macs.

Under the project settings, I only see options for 32-bit Intel, 64-bit Intel, and Standard (32/64 Intel).  Should I be seeing a "Universal Binary" entry here?

I don't have any problem running it under 10.4 on an Intel Mac.  I was careful not to use features that don't work under 10.4, and I think I set the project settings correctly to allow it to be backward-compatible to 10.4.  It's just that I can't figure out how to get it to compile for PPC.

I'm flailing around, trying to figure out how to build a universal binary, and I think I'm probably just missing something obvious.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IIRC, PowerPC support is an optional install feature of Xcode 3. The option you are looking for should be called _Standard (32/64-bit Universal)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to choose one of the predefined settings for the Architectures build setting.  You can choose "Other..." and then explicitly enter a list of architectures like ppc, i386, x86_64.

By the way, there are extra tricks if you need to run on G3s:  You must use GCC 4.0 and the 10.4 SDK.